# XSL transform - remove duplicate

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt

I am still struggling a little with XPath.

Current XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <table_1 dropdown1="Item1"></table_1>
    <listitems key1="Item1" name="" key2="Id2"/>
    <listitems key1="Item1" name="Item A" key2="Id2"/>
    <listitems key1="Item1" name="Item B" key2="Id2"/>
    <listitems key1="Item1" name="" key2="Id4"/>
    <listitems key1="Item1" name="Item A" key2="Id4"/>
    <listitems key1="Item1" name="Item B" key2="Id4"/>
    <listitems key1="Item2" name="" key2="Id6"/>
    <listitems key1="Item2" name="Item C" key2="Id6"/>
    <listitems key1="Item2" name="Item D" key2="Id6"/>
</data>
```

Current XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>           

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Untitled</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="/data/listitems[@key1=/data/table_1/@dropdown1]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>                    
                    <br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="listitems">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, ' ')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current Result:

[image]

Comment: rod, you haven't given us something very important -- please, provide the exact wanted result from the transformation. This might help the reader understand what grouping is wanted -- unless you also specify the requirements for grouping. Remember one basic pronciple: Never leave the reader to guess what actually is wanted. Please.

Comment: Are you supposed to have you first 6 `listitem` elements all with `key1="Item1"`? Your code isn't duplicating anything, Item A and Item B both exist twice, and both with the same `key1` value.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev The unique values I'm trying to obtain will populate a dropdownlist. I'm using the name attribute values as the items for the dropdownlist.

Comment: @Flynn1179 I know it seems strange to have the data that way but I have no control over XML part so I have to try to fix it on the XSL side.

Comment: @rod: So, what is the XML representation of this "dropdownlist"? And what is your definition of "unique"? Please, edit the question and provide the exact wanted XML result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you consider `<listitems>` elements with the same `name` attribute as duplicates, you can use XPath's `preceding-sibling` axis to ignore any elements that are duplicates:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/data/listitems[@key1=/data/table_1/@dropdown1][not(@name = preceding-sibling::listitems/@name)]">
```

That means, you select all the items you selected, with the additional restriction that there not be any preceding `<listitems>` sibling element whose `name` attribute has the same value as that of the element being tested.

Comment: I tried replacing my for-each line with yours but I'm still getting duplicate. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @rod: Sorry, this was overly complex and contained a typo; I have edited my answer and tested the new version; any duplicates are skipped for me now.

Comment: Does the 2nd pair of brackets indicate something? I'm thinking like SQL where it seems there should be like an AND separating the 2 conditions.

Comment: @rod: You can write several conditions within the same pair of brackets and couple them with the `and` operator, or you can write them into two sets of brackets where they too will be and-ed. You can read each pair of brackets as a restriction, and only nodes where all restrictions apply will be selected.

Comment: Great thanks for the insight. I've been to the W3Schools website do you have any references for this kind of stuff that you can share with an XSLT newbie.

Comment: @rod: I've always found the [location paths examples from the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths) to be quite helpful. Note how some of them feature several pairs of brackets, while the natural language-description mentions that both conditions have to be fulfilled. There, it also becomes evident that under certain circumstances the order of the conditions is important. When just coupling conditions like the ones here, this is not significant, though.

Comment: This is not a good answer - see here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. Note that in XSLT 2.0 and higher you can use the `distinct-values()` function.